# Static content does not sends by IIS

Tags: iis, static

The IIS 7.5 (Windows 2008 R2) does not send static content fully. It means that some images and css are loads correctly and some images or css does not appears, only if I press F5 site loaded fully.
I searched a lot about this problem and can say that:
- problem not in cache;
- 'Static Content' IIS setting is installed;
- firewall works correctly;
- cross browser problem;

Comment: Do you have an example of a failing URL?

Answer (score 0):

Open your site in IE9. Press F12 to open up the developer tools, switch to the network tab and click the buton called start capturing.

Reload the page until you reproduce the loading errors you report.

Click stop capturing.

Use this report and look at the result coloumn, are you getting 404 or 404.2 errors?